# Why am I getting "unexpected end of file"?

Tags: bash

I was following [this](http://rsalveti.wordpress.com/2007/04/03/bash-parsing-arguments-with-getopts/) tutorial on parsing arguments. When I run my script with or without arguments I get "line 45: syntax error: unexpected end of file".
This is the line after the last line in the script. I simply don't see the error though (new to bash scripting...).

```
#!/bin/bash

#Explain arguments that can be passed in
argumentUsage(){
    cat << EOF
    usage: $0 options

    This script configures rsync to backup SOURCE to DESTINATION and provide notifications on status.

    OPTIONS:
       -h    Show this message
       -s    Source location
       -d    Destination location
    EOF
}

DESTINATION=
SOURCE=

while getopts "hs:d:" OPTION
do 
   case $OPTION in
    h)
       argumentUsage()
       exit1
       ;;
    s)
       SOURCE=$OPTARG
       ;;
    d)
       DESTINATION=$OPTARG
       ;;
    ?)
       argumentUsage()
       exit
       ;;
   esac
done
```

Comment: Also, for calling a function, you should not specify `()`. Change `argumentUsage()` to `argumentUsage` in the switch case entries.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's because you indented the `EOF` here

```
argumentUsage(){
     ...
     OPTIONS:
       -h    Show this message
       -s    Source location
       -d    Destination location
     EOF
}
```

Due to the indentation, bash doesn't "see" the terminating `EOF`, so effectively your here-doc is unterminated, which leads to “unexpected end of file”.

Comment: @anishsane, shouldn't this comment be posted on the question? I'm just showing the relevant spot in the function definition.